# Join Multiple Data frames in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am Implementing a project where MySql data is imported to hdfs using sqoop. It had nearly 30 tables.I am reading each table as a dataframe by inferring schema and registered as temp tables. I has few questions in doing this...
1. There several joins need to implemented for the tables suppose say df1 to df10 . In MySQL the query will be 
`select a.id,b.name,c.AccountName from accounts a priority b bills c where a.id=b.id and c.name=a.name` 
Instead of using 
`sqlContext.sql(select a.id,b.name,c.AccountName from accounts a priority b bills c where a.id=b.id and c.name=a.name)`
Is there other to join all the data frames effectively based on conditions..

2. Is it the correct way to convert tables to data frames and querying on top of them or any better way to approach this type of joins and querying in spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similiar problem and I end up Using :

`val df_list = ListBuffer[DataFrame]()
df_list .toList.reduce((a, b) => a.join(b, a.col(a.schema.head.name) === b.col(b.schema.head.name), "left_outer"))`

You could make a free sql statement on Sqoop and join everything there. Or Use Spark JDBC  to do the same job

Comment: `val df_list = ListBuffer[DataFrame]()
df_list .toList.reduce((a, b) => a.join(b, a.col(a.schema.head.name) === b.col(b.schema.head.name), "left_outer"))`. I haven't understood this ... If you can explain me with example that will be great

Comment: df_list is a list of dataframes on your case [accounts, priority, bills], the rest  is just joining all dataframes on the first column

Comment: 's got it but I need to join these dataframe's on multiple conditions like where  a.id=b.id and c.name=a.name) and many more on the where condition